# Problems and with which algorithm technique they can be solved?

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for a list of problems (the more the problems the better) with their corresponding algorithm technique(s) these problems can be solved.
For example:

Shortest Path problem -> Dijkstra's algorithm (dynamic programming), and maybe others ...

Knapsack problem -> can be solved with dynamic programming, ...

Convex Hull problem -> could be done by divide and conquer, ...

If in every problem there is a small paragraph explaining how the problem is solved (e.g. it could explain how to "divide" the problem in a divide and conquer algorithm) with the given
technique that would be even better.

Is there any such list available in the net or in a book?

**UPDATE after locking ... **

I'm not looking for problems mostly found in programming contests like [TopCoder](http://topcoder.com). Problems from such sites (contests) use to "hide" the problem definition which is supposed to be found by the user. I'm looking for problem definitions, like **Given a graph G = (V, E) ...**  and it's given solution technique **Could be solved using divide and conquer ...** instead of problems definitions like this:  **Given N houses, John tries to find a path to go home as fast as possible ...**  which are how problems are described in programming contests sites.

This question has nothing to do with homework as some people thought. I want to "exercise" my algorithm solution technique skills. By knowing that a given problem can be solved by a given technique will help me try to find a solution using this technique and so I guess will get a deeper understanding of each technique, plus I will be become a better algorithm solver.

Comment: You may start with this [list of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms).

Comment: You're asking for multiple answers to multiple questions.  StackOverflow works best when you ask a single question that can be answered with a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

The site [Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Main_Page) categories many problems (but not all) from [UVa online judge](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa) and [Sphere Online Judge](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Sphere_Online_Judge). For example, here is the [partial category listing for UVa Volume I](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_Volume_I). Also check their [Categories](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Special%3aCategories) page.

Answer (score 2):

[Topcoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive) categorizes each problem from every past contest they held. Besides that, you can filter problems by difficulty, as well as read editorials or other people's solutions.